# Is it possible to write a public api with Parse SDK?

Tags: flutter, networking, parse-platform, request, rest

I am currently writing a web shop application, whose backend will be host at Parse SDK.
I want to add a funcitonality to my app, that if i get an API request to the server to create a new listing.
The API will be called from other apps(I want them to inttegrate it in their system, so if they make a new listing on their personal site, than it will create a new listing on my site too by calling that api).
I want to know if this is possible, I need authentication too, and I want to know if it is possible without providing them my DB application id and rest api key.

Comment: The easiest way is via Cloud Functions: https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-functions. But Parse Server is essentially an Express.js middleware, meaning that you can create other custom routes to the main Express.js app in which Parse Server is running.

Comment: Could you provide me an example on how to add custom routes to main Express.js app?

Comment: You can refer to the Express.js documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html